# <list> of parent, do for each subclass

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, xna, subclass

So, I have a class GameObject, that I am using as a base for many subclasses.

```
class GameObject()
{
    blah;
}

class AmmoBox() : Gameobject()
{
    different blah;
}

class Taco() : GameObject() {very different blah;}
```

Later I use them in a list and I want to specify different update/etc behavior for each subclass.

```
foreach (AmmoBox a in GameObjects) { }

foreach (Taco t in GameObjects) { }
```

Compiler throws error "unable to cast object of type 'GameObject' to type 'AmmoBox'. I know this is a pathetic mistake, how should I properly do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `OfType` to filter based on the type:

```
foreach (AmmoBox a in GameObjects.OfType<AmmoBox>()) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast them in the `foreach(..)` directly, try looping through them and checking if they are of the type you want. Use the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator to check this, it will return the casted object if it was of the type, or null if it was not.

```
foreach (GameObject object in GameObjects)
{
     AmmoBox a = object as AmmoBox;
     if (a != null)
     {
         //Do something with a
     }

     Taco t = object as Taco;
     if (taco != null)
     {
         //Do something with t
     }
}
```

You could also use LINQ's [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension to select them based on their type.

```
foreach (AmmoBox a in GameObjects.OfType<AmmoBox>())
{
     //Do something with a
}
foreach (Taco t in GameObjects.OfType<Taco>())
{
     //Do something with a
}
```

Comment: Would either method be better applicable to 100 or so types? And many thanks!

Comment: Only way is to test them yourself, although 100 types shouldn't be too difficult for either to handle.

Comment: Thanks again, new to this community, any way to +1 you? Anything I can do?

Comment: Just a question, wouldn't the "OfType" solution use more resources than the "as" operator?

Comment: I think so, I'll look it up later

Comment: One last problem I cannot use the foreach loop as I need to be able to enumerate each object for methods later. So I'm embedding them in for loops. I seem to run into outofbounds exception when using the first method. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code, if your using a for loop make sure you start at 0 and use < not <=

Answer (score 1):

The `GameObjects` variable contains different types of GameObjects. So when you try to cast to a mismatched type, it throws an error.

One way is to filter the collection as you iterate through it. This involves checking for the actual type of the object. This is OK in simple cases, but is not really considered "good" code as it defeats the purpose of using an interface.

Instead, try and create an `Update` method in each of your GameObjects. Like so:

```
abstract class GameObject
{
    ...
    public abstract void Update();
}

class Ammo : GameObject
{
    public override void Update()
    {
        // Stuff to update Ammo
    }
}
```

Do similar for your other game objects. Then in your foreach loop, just call this one method on each object.

```
foreach (GameObject g in GameObjects)
{
    g.Update();
}
```

This is nice and clean. It also abstracts away specific details into the specific classes. This is a well-known design pattern called the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).